# Get all link id from html source code using PREG_MATCH_ALL

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I know i shouldn't do this that way but its just to retrieve all id of my links since i have a lot of them

Here is the patern:

`<a href="mylink.php?get=123456">Click 1</a>
<a href="mylink.php?get=222222">Click 2</a>
<a href="mylink.php?get=81456">Click 3</a>
<a href="mylink.php?get=1700">Click 4</a>`

I want to get all "get=" values (123456, 222222, etc.)
And also the "Click 1", "Click 2", etc values using Preg_match_all()

Any idea?

Thanks a lot guys!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, http://rubular.com/r/B02pLhfRsq

```
/<a href="mylink.php\?get=(.*?)\">(.*?)<\/a>/i
```